# JAXB / XJC: Generate classes from elements with same complexType

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I would like to generate the Java classes `SignResponse` and `AuthResponse` from the following XSD using XJC:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="SignResponse" type="tns:OrderResponseType"/>
    <xsd:element name="AuthResponse" type="tns:OrderResponseType"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="OrderResponseType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="orderRef" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="autoStartToken" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

This means generating classes from elements with same complexType. Using the above XSD as input, XJC will generate an `OrderResponseType` class, but no `SignResponse` and `AuthResponse`. It seems `type="tns:OrderResponseType"` is not used properly by XJC, because when `OrderResponseType` is defined inside `SignResponse` and `AuthResponse`, everything works OK:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="SignResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="orderRef" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="autoStartToken" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="AuthResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="orderRef" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="autoStartToken" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Using the following XJB, `type="tns:OrderResponseType"` is actually used, but this works only when there is only one element that has `type="tns:OrderResponseType"` as attribute:

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
          xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">

    <jxb:globalBindings>
         <xjc:simple/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

Using multiple elements in combination with this `<xjc:simple/>` XJB binding element will cause only `OrderResponseType` to be generated.

Using custom bindings like:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='OrderResponseType']">
     <jxb:class name="SignResponse"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

also works only for one element. XJC will throw an exception when using e.g.:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='OrderResponseType']">
     <jxb:class name="SignResponse"/>
</jxb:bindings>
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='OrderResponseType']">
     <jxb:class name="AuthResponse"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, because `SignResponse`'s and `AuthResponse`'s base class will be `JAXBElement<OrderResponseType>`, not `OrderResponseType`. But you can have two different classes using the following jaxb bindings:

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='SignResponse']">
        <jxb:class name="SignResponse"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='AuthResponse']">             
       <jxb:class name="AuthResponse"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: We ended up using OrderResponseType instead of SignResponse and AuthResponse.