# Can you force JAXB2 Maven plugin to create a Java class from "empty" element?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have an XSD Schema with the following element:

```
<xs:element name="FooResponse" type="commonTypes:Response" />
```

When I run the build (which has a `xjc` goal for converting the schema to Java sources), a separate class file `FooResponse.java` is not created (probably because it would be identical to `Response.java`. Now, I know I can rewrite the schema like this:

```
<xs:element name="FooResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="commonTypes:Request"/>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

and get the result I'm looking for. However, the schema is automatically generated from a tool, and I'd rather not have to touch it manually. Is there a way to configure the plugin to create the source file in this situation?

I need to get both `Response.java` and `FooResponse.java` created, as there are other types unrelated to `FooResponse` that need to inherit from that.

I tried creating an XJB binding file like this:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="my_schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='FooResponse']">
            <jaxb:class name="FooResponse"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

This works in that I get both `Response.java` and `FooResponse.java` but the contents of `FooResponse` is not exactly what I'd like:

```
public class FooResponse
    extends JAXBElement<Response>
{

    protected final static QName NAME = new QName("initech.com/c/m", "FooResponse");

    public FooResponse(Response value) {
        super(NAME, ((Class) Response.class), null, value);
    }

    public FooResponse() {
        super(NAME, ((Class) Response.class), null, null);
    }

}
```

This would be exactly what I want if I got it to extend `Response` directly without wrapping it into a `JAXBElement`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAXB: How to change XJC-generated classes names when attr type is specified in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793637/jaxb-how-to-change-xjc-generated-classes-names-when-attr-type-is-specified-in-x) You should be able to adjust the `node` xpath in the answer to your element.

Comment: Not exact duplicate, though it may have prodded me in the correct direction. That question is about renaming (in my case) `Response` to `FooResponse`. I need to keep both `Response` and `FooResponse`, because there are other types that are derived from `Response` that should not change their parent type to `FooResponse`.

Comment: This question is actually closer to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399861/jaxb-xjc-generate-classes-from-elements-with-same-complextype

Comment: [tag:maven-jaxb2-plugin] does not have an `xjc` goal.

Comment: Why do you actually need this?

Comment: This is `jaxb2-maven-plugin` from `org.codehaus.mojo` which does have an xjc goal. Without going too much into details, I need this for a work related thing where XML payloads defined in schemas are passed around as messages.

Comment: Currently it kinda does what I need, if the type is put into a different package than where it is referenced, the plugin creates a factory method for creating the response, but that one has the `JAXBElement<Response>` wrapper too, which may be troublesome when marshalling messages to/from the message queue.